# Trouble with tables in html and css

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if you could help me with this problem:
I'm making a table in html and i want to have space between cells but i also need the cell with the heading and the text to be collapsed. So is there a way to just collapse the borders with the th and td tags?

[I want to remove the space marked with red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1zB8.png)

Comment: Show us a working sample or any image to get a better idea of what your problem is.

Comment: I recommend using padding. Just collapse everything and then add padding to `<td>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no; you cannot collapse some borders in a table while keeping others separated. So you should look for other solutions.

One would be omitting the `th` altogether and putting the all the info in the `td`, by using a `figure` with a `figcaption`.

```css
body {
  background: #c0d0e0;
  margin: 1em
}

table {
  border-spacing: 1em
}

td {
  background:white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 0
}

figure {
  display: block;
  margin: 0
}

figcaption {
  background: #d1d1d1;
  padding: .333em;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #6e6e6e;
}

figure img {
  display: block;
  margin: 1em;
  border-radius:.667em;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <figure>
        <figcaption>caption for image 1</figcaption>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/101/100" alt="one" />
      </figure>
    </td>
    <td>
      <figure>
        <figcaption>caption for image 2</figcaption>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/102/100" alt="two" />
      </figure>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <figure>
        <figcaption>caption for image 3</figcaption>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/103/100" alt="three" />
      </figure>
    </td>
    <td>
      <figure>
        <figcaption>caption for image 4</figcaption>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/104/100" alt="four" />
      </figure>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```